# Pinch to zoom in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, model-view-controller, raphael

I have a **raphael.js** based project containing raphael elements and I can pinch to zoom in **IE 11** on industrial pc screen but cannot pinch to **zoom** in **chrome**. As I researched chrome does not support pinch to **zoom**...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the command line option --enable-pinch after the shortcut to chrome.exe

Example, if Chrome is located here

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

You can run it touch enabled by making a shortcut to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-pinch